# Parsing url string from '+' to '%2B'

Tags: python, url, encode

I have url address where its extension needs to be in `ASCII/UTF-8`

```
a='sAE3DSRAfv+HG='
```

i need to convert above as this:

```
a='sAE3DSRAfv%2BHG%3D'
```

I searched but not able to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see built-in method [urllib.parse.quote()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote)

A very important task for the URL is its safe transmission. Its meaning must not change after you created it till it is received by the intended receiver. To achieve that end URL encoding was incorporated. See [RFC 2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)

URL might contain non-ascii characters like cafés, López etc. Or it might contain symbols which have different meaning when put in the context of a URL. For example, # which signifies a bookmark. To ensure safe transmitting of such characters HTTP standards maintain that you quote the url at the point of origin. And URL is always present in quoted format to anyone else.

I have put sample usage below.

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> a='sAE3DSRAfv+HG='
>>> urllib.parse.quote(a)
'sAE3DSRAfv%2BHG%3D'
>>>
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Comment: Thanks! Added more details.